# R: Turning row into columns - Identifying values_from in pivot_wider

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following dataset

| Pet Shop | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | dog | fish | cat |
| A | fish | fish | cat |
| B | turtle | cat | turtle |
| A | dog | cat | turtle |
| B | cat | rabbit | dog |
| C | rabbit | dog | rabbit |
| C | dog | cat | fish |

```
df = structure(list(Pet.Shop = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C"
               ), Day1 = c("dog", "fish", "turtle", "dog", "cat", "rabbit", 
               "dog"), Day2 = c("fish", "fish", "cat", "cat", "rabbit", "dog", 
               "cat"), Day3 = c("cat", "cat", "turtle", "turtle", "dog", "rabbit", 
               "fish")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I'm trying to get the following output using pivot_wider

| Pet Shop | dog | cat | fish | turtle | rabbit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

My code is as follows but I'm not sure what to indicate for values_from.

```
new_df <- df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = XXX) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Appreciate any help. Open to suggestions apart from pivot_wider as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' and then do the wide conversion

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Day"), names_to = NULL) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value,
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  Pet.Shop   dog  fish   cat turtle rabbit
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1 A            1     1     1      0      0
2 A            0     2     1      0      0
3 B            0     0     1      2      0
4 A            1     0     1      1      0
5 B            1     0     1      0      1
6 C            1     0     0      0      2
7 C            1     1     1      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have difficulties to understand `values_fn = length` (like me) each time. Here is the same code of @akrun, just without `values_fn = length`:

There are some interesting features in @akrun's code:

1. `names_to = NULL` so we do not have to remove name at the end
2. assigning `names_from` and `values_from` to one column `value`
3. creating an unique identifier `row` so that each row in the original data frame can be uniquely identified after reshaping.Also important for counting in the grouped state `count(Pet.Shop, row, value)`
4. `values_fill = 0` to fill NAs with 0.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
  
df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Day"), names_to = NULL) %>% 
  count(Pet.Shop, row, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

```
 Pet.Shop   cat   dog  fish turtle rabbit
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1 A            1     1     1      0      0
2 A            1     0     2      0      0
3 A            1     1     0      1      0
4 B            1     0     0      2      0
5 B            1     1     0      0      1
6 C            0     1     0      0      2
7 C            1     1     1      0      0
```